# How to get value of DataModel field in code behind without using an Entry control on Xaml page in MAUI C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I'm new to C# and MAUI - so thank you for your help!

---

#### What I have:

I've created a very simple 2 page application that works great:

1. **Page 1** uses a `CollectionView` to display a list of names defined by `MyDataModel` (FirstName, LastName, ID).  If the user selects an item in the list, then the program navigates to a detail page for that item.
2. **Page 2** displays the FirstName and LastName of the selected item using `{Binding}` to fill `<Entry />` controls, plus a Submit button to commit any changes to my database.  I do not want to use an `<Entry />` to display the ID field to the user.

#### What I need:

On my details page: **How do I reference the value of MyDataModel's ID if I don't have an `<Entry />` for it?**

For example:

```
MyDataModel MyRecord = new MyDataModel();
MyRecord.FirstName = FirstNameEntry.Text;   // Value from Xaml Entry
MyRecord.LastName = LastNameEntry.Text;     // Value from Xaml Entry
MyRecord.ID = __________;                   // How do I get this value without an Xaml Entry?
```

**More detailed code below.**

---

### Data Model

Simple data model with 3 fields per record

```
public class MyDataModel
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

### Collection View Page Code Behind

Collection View Selection Changed

```
private async void OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() != null)
        {
            MyDataModel MySelectedItem = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as MyDataModel;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage
            {
                BindingContext = MySelectedItem 
            });
        }
    }
```

### Detail Page Xaml

`<Entry />` fields on Detail Page in Xaml

```
<Entry 
    x:Name="FirstNameEntry"
    Text="{Binding FirstName}" />

<Entry 
    x:Name="LastNameEntry"
    Text="{Binding LastName}" />
```

### Detail Page Code Behind

**How to access value of ID for this record without a Xaml `<Entry />` for it?**

```
public DetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

private async void Submit_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDataModel MyRecord = new MyDataModel();
        MyRecord.FirstName = FirstNameEntry.Text;
        MyRecord.LastName = LastNameEntry.Text;
        MyRecord.ID = ___How Do I Get ID Without Using an XAML Entry?___;   // int.Parse(IdEntry.Text);
        await SaveRecord(MyRecord);
    }
```

#### Thank you

Comment: `DetailPage`'s `BindingContext` contains the entire model already, you don't need to create a new instance of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass the model via the constructor

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage(MySelectedItem));
```

then in `DetailPage`

```
private MyDataModel model;

public DetailPage(MyDataModel data)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    BindingContext = model = data;
}

private async void Submit_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // you are using data binding, so you do not
   // explicitly need to set any property values
   await SaveRecord(model);
}
```

Comment: Perfect ~ I never would've thought of ```BindingContext = model = data;```.  Thank you!